# VS Code debugger won't run

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a python script but when I start the debugger on this file, the pause/step into/step over/etc. window pops up for about a second then disappears. Nothing shows up in the terminal or debug console. I have breakpoints set in my code but they are not encountered.

I'm using the default "Python: Current File" launch config. I've tried restarting VS Code, reinstalling VS Code, reinstalling the Python extension but nothing has helped.

Comment: Hmm... Can you start a regular terminal session? What OS are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by regular terminal session? I'm running VS Code on Windows SSHed to a Linux machine

Comment: Try running the VSCode command **Terminal: Create New Terminal** (`workbench.action.terminal.new`).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your launch.json

Comment: In what way? OP said they're using the default config, which should work, no?

Comment: It is set up
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}